# Iframe working with cypress test cases run in google crome but not work with fire fox

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I am try to get Iframe content input field to type input value using code.
I have declared "chromeWebSecurity": false in cypress.json file.so it's work in google crome browser.But not work in fire fox browser.

```
            return cy.get(`iframe[id=${id}]`)
                .its('0.contentDocument').should('exist')
        }

        const getIframeBody = (id) => {
            
            return getIframeDocument(id)
                .its('body').should('not.be.undefined')
                .then(cy.wrap)
        }

        getIframeBody('field-name' ).find('#fieldname').type('fieldValue');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no ability to disable to webSecurity for firefox like Chrome, we all have to live with it, unfortunately.